# json response showing one result instead of three in php

Tags: php

JSON response dumps only **one** result instead of **three**.

I need to get json response in the following json format. it contains **three** result

```
{"entries":[{"id":"1A","content_no":101},
            {"id":"1B","content_no":102},
            {"id":"1C","content_no":103}
]}
```

When I run the code below as per json result:

```
// curl result
//echo  $result;
$json = json_decode($result, true);

// initial post variable

$post= [];
foreach($json['entries'] as $data){

  // printed three result successfilly in for each loop
  $id = $data['id'];
  $content_no = $data['content_no'];


  // Now to get the result in the required json format and dump it or echo it outside for each loop
  $entries = array();
  $entries['id'] = $data['id'];
  $entries['content_no'] = data['content_no'];

  $params = array();
  $params['entries'][] = $entries;
  $post = json_encode($params);

}

// send post result in json format to database
var_dump($post);
```

The for each loops prints the 3 results but my problem is that only one result is var dumped as per json  below. I was wondering where the other 2 results are hiding. please how do I get the remaining 2 results as per json format above

```
{"entries":[{"id":"1C","content_no":103}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're always setting the `$params` variable as a new array, so it turns into a new array and when you do `$post = json_encode($params);` you're always getting the last index result.

Basically, you should initialize the `$params` array only out of the loop.

Comment: Also, for improving code quality, I believe you should do the `$post = json_encode($params)` only once and outside the loop after collecting all your data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code (I assume - ignore them if you have different results), but the main thing is that you `json_encode()` the value inside the loop rather than build a list of the data and then encode it (Notes of changes to errors in the code)...

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);

$post= [];
foreach($json['entries'] as $data){   // Change from $json_result

    // printed three result successfilly in for each loop
    $id = $data['id'];
    $content_no = $data['content_no'];


    // Now to get the result in the required json format and dump it or echo it outside for each loop
    $entries = array();
    $entries['id'] = $data['id'];
    $entries['content_no'] = $data['content_no'];   // Change from data['content_no'];

    $post['entries'][] = $entries;  // Just add new data to $post instead

}
// Encode total of all data
$post = json_encode($post);

var_dump($post);
```

gives...

```
string(100) "{"entries":[{"id":"1A","content_no":101},
    {"id":"1B","content_no":102},
    {"id":"1C","content_no":103}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are "clean" your `post` always in loop, just update it.

```php
<?php 

// curl result
//echo  $result;
$json = json_decode($result, true);

// initial post variable
$post= [];
foreach($json['entries'] as $data){

    // printed three result successfilly in for each loop
    $id = $data['id'];
    $content_no = $data['content_no'];


    // Now to get the result in the required json format and dump it or echo it outside for each loop
    $entries = array();
    $entries['id'] = $data['id'];
    $entries['content_no'] = data['content_no'];

    $post['entries'][] = $entries;
}

// send post result in json format to database
var_dump($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, just change following two lines.

1

```
$entries['content_no'] = data['content_no'];
```

to

```
$entries['content_no'] = $data['content_no']; //were only missing a $ variable sign
```

2

```
$post = json_encode($params);
```

to

```
$post[] = json_encode($params); //you defined an array but you were not pushing data in to the array
```